# Errors while installing NumPy for Python 3.6 on MacOS 10.10

Tags: macos, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to install NumPy on my MacOS 10.10 with Python 3.6. I am new to Python. I get the errors shown below. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions to overcome this. I tried the following:

**First Approach**
$ brew install homebrew/python/numpy
Error: /usr/local/Cellar is not writable. You should change the
ownership and permissions of /usr/local/Cellar back to your
user account:
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Cellar
==> Tapping homebrew/python
fatal: could not create work tree dir '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-python': Permission denied
Error: Failure while executing: git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-python /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-python --depth=1

**Second Approach**
$ pip3 install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.12.0-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/utils/**init**.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 220, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy'
$

Comment: It seems you have problems with user permissions on your computer. For the second approach, did you try $ sudo pip3 ....?

Answer (score 1):

use the anaconda distribution!
it will install inside your user directories
and save you any sudo headaches. And get you
a functioning numpy/scipy stack.

https://www.continuum.io/downloads